# will the jobs need to be reconfigured after we update any Plugins in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Willing to update plug-ins in the jenkins windows machine, I have used those plug-ins in many jobs as required, So once update completes, will the jobs automatically works fine, or should I change configuration on each job, after the update.

Comment: from my experience, the jobs will typically continue to work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a plugin update changes something at its configuration there's usually an according message attached in *Manage Jenkins* →  *Manage Plugins* → ***Updates***.

Comment: Thanks Gerold Broser, so if the warning message shows up in the plugin Manager Like this " Jobs using this plugin may need to be reconfigured,...Contued",then we should consider check the message, so this means all other plugins which has no such warnings can be updated anytime, am I understood properly? please correct me If I am wrong?

Comment: @user3227730 Yes, if the plugin devs did their homework and no such message appears it's pretty safe to update.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends - there might be an update of a plugin that is not backward compatible. In theory you should learn about such breaking change from description of new version, either on the plugin website or in Jenkins itself in plugin "to be updated" section.